# Copied folder is somehow connected to main folder

Tags: macos, file-copy

I am trying to backup my google drive data because I'm out of storage and have no intention of buying cloud storage (also read as "cheap").

What I did was, I downloaded the Google Drive desktop client, and then zipped the "My Drive" folder and saved it on my laptop.

Now, the strange thing I notice is that if I delete a file in my "My Drive" folder, it also gets deleted in my copied folder.

What am I doing wrong?

Outline of my steps below:

```
1. Compress "My Drive" folder
2. Transfer .zip file to Desktop
3. Unzip file at Desktop, location is ~/User/Desktop/My Drive
4. Delete a file "myfile.gsheet" in My Drive"
5. See it magically disappear in ~/User/Desktop/My Drive as well.
```

OS: MacOS

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Cheers!

Comment: Are any of the folders symlinks rather than actual folders?

Comment: I don't understand symlinks, but there is a distinct arrow at the bottom of the folder when I see it in finder.

Comment: `ls -l` in the terminal from the parent folder of "My Drive" should tell you whether or not it's a symlink. (It'll start with "l" instead of "d" on the left and there will be an arrow `->` on the right pointing to the target location.) If so, I suspect both the one you zipped and the copy are both links; you just zipped the link and not its target folder. I'm not a mac user, so I don't know what the icons with arrows mean and I don't know the usual tooling for zipping folders and how to make it follow the links instead when zipping, or the correct commands to use. Hopefully someone else will.

Comment: Yes, it's showing "l" instead of "d". How do I remove the symlink? I tried `unlink` (looking at a tutorial online) but it says `/Users/My Drive is a directory`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @frabjous I figured out that I was zipping and copying a symbolic link. (Dammit!)

Instead, I went inside the folder and used `rsync` instead. It was super fast and awesome!